# SUM DISTINCT based off a specific column?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am attempting to sum the balance of each customer only once. Normally I would use a SUM DISTINCT expression, however, one column is throwing it off and the row is no longer "Distinct".

For example:

```
Customer Number - Customer Name - Exception Type - Balance
CIF13443        - Paul          - 1              - 125
CIF13452        - Ryan          - 2              - 85
CIF13443        - Paul          - 3              - 125
CIF13765        - Linda         - 1              - 90
```

In this case, if I use SUM DISTINCT, Paul's balance will be summed up twice simply because he has a different exception type, where in fact I only want SSRS to sum each customer once. One way would be to SUM the "Balance" of only DISTINCT customer numbers. Possibly by grouping the Customer Number? Is that possible on SSRS? I would rather not touch the SQL Dataset.

Thanks!

Any input is appreciated.

Comment: Well if you need the Exception Type in the output you will have to include it in the group by. That is how aggregates work. If it didn't which value would you want to see?

Comment: `SUM() OVER...`

Comment: Sean, I have the exception types included so that I could see the totals per Exception Type. However, when doing a grand total, I would only like to see the SUM of unique customer numbers.

Comment: scsimon, can you explain? I am not familiar with that expression.

Comment: Can you provide an expected output first? The current data set doesn't need an aggregation unless you care to take into account Exception Types

Comment: I would like the grant total to be: 300. Where currently it would end up being 425.

Comment: When you get aggregated data it is per group. What you are saying doesn't work. You get the sum per group. If you want a grand total row that should be done in your report.

Comment: I do have a total row, and like I said, it is spitting out the sum of all the rows. Is there a way around this? Where it will get the sums based on the distinct customer number?

Comment: You keep using SUM DISTINCT. I don't think it does what you think it does.

Comment: SUM DISTINCT is an expression that sums up the unique fields. I am simply using that vocabulary to express my question

Comment: @StevenWhite  Inconcievable  (Sorry, had to say it.)

Answer (score -1):

you can use union to dustinct the duplicate line:

**Query 1(Using Union):**

```
    ;WITH testdata(CustomerNumber,CustomerName,ExceptionType,Balance)AS(
      SELECT 'CIF13443','Paul','1',125 UNION all
      SELECT 'CIF13452','Ryan ','2',85 UNION all
      SELECT 'CIF13443','Paul','3',125 UNION all
      SELECT 'CIF13765','Linda','1',90
  )
  SELECT CustomerNumber,CustomerName,Balance FROM testdata UNION SELECT NULL,NULL,NULL WHERE 1!=1
/*
  SELECT CustomerNumber,CustomerName,SUM(t.Balance) AS total_balance 
  FROM (
       SELECT CustomerNumber,CustomerName,Balance FROM testdata UNION SELECT NULL,NULL,NULL
  ) AS t WHERE CustomerNumber IS NOT null
  GROUP BY CustomerNumber,CustomerName
*/
```

```
CustomerNumber CustomerName Balance
-------------- ------------ -----------
CIF13443       Paul         125
CIF13452       Ryan         85
CIF13765       Linda        90
```

**Using windows function pick one line for the duplicate lines:**

```
;WITH testdata(CustomerNumber,CustomerName,ExceptionType,Balance)AS(
  SELECT 'CIF13443','Paul','1',125 UNION all
  SELECT 'CIF13452','Ryan ','2',85 UNION all
  SELECT 'CIF13443','Paul','3',125 UNION all
  SELECT 'CIF13765','Linda','1',90
```

)

```
SELECT CustomerNumber,CustomerName,SUM(t.Balance) AS total_balance 
FROM (
  SELECT CustomerNumber,CustomerName,Balance,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY CustomerNumber,CustomerName,Balance ORDER BY testdata.ExceptionType) seq FROM testdata 
) AS t WHERE t.seq=1
GROUP BY CustomerNumber,CustomerName
```

Comment: Using UNION to force a distinct sort in this scenario is pointless and will lead to confusion and maintenance headaches for the next developer.  If the best solution is to use a distinct sort in SQL, say that instead.

Comment: @WesH I gave another query.